# How to decide at which level your solution should be deployed?

Tags: deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explain it to me: SharePoint deployment scope, solution and features](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/explain-it-to-me-sharepoint-deployment-scope-solution-and-features)

I found there are many levels to deploy solutions in share point. How to decide at which level the solution should be deployed?

Are there any guidelines and best practices available for this?