# Aggregate data from multiple site collections in SharePoint online

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I have a question about showing data from multiple site collections in SharePoint online.

I want each customer to have it's own site. This should be a site collection because if I make it a normal site and I create a task list, the customer is able to see other customers when assigning a task.

What I want to do is the following. Every customer has a site collection with a question list in it. On the root site I want to show all questions for all customers. I've already done such a thing with a keywordquery in a farm solution.

To show data from multiple site collections in sharepoint online sandboxed solution I've tried:

- using a keywordquery
- using the search.asmx webservice

But unfortunately both can't be used in a sandboxed solution. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily we have a content search web part now and it is possible to add that keywordquery in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Lists.asmx web service and the GetListItems method. 
(I know it's an old question but it came up as one of the top search results so figured it might be worth answering)

Answer (score 0):

For the scope you require you can't use sand boxed solutions, this is because by the very nature of your requirement it is a farm level task.

[Here is a great post on scopes and solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/explain-it-to-me-sharepoint-deployment-scope-solution-and-features)

[Workflows updating across site collections](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) this should work fine with office365 however it isn't as fast as using the object model, so use with care.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't understand why it is a farm level task. I want a simple webpart that shows data from a list (for example questions) that is in multiple site collections. In my webpart I want to show all questions. Looks like it is possible [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/01/03/how-to-query-people-search-in-sharepoint-online-and-other-sharepoint-platforms-too.aspx) but I don't want to use silverlight.

Comment: changed my post a little bit to explain why I want to aggregate the data :)

Comment: If the lists are on separate site collections the scope becomes farm level as apposed to site level ( on one site collection ). You can delegate and spoof yourself as the farm administrator and deploy a single farm level web part to do this. However the solution is still farm level because of the requirement of where the code should be stored. Can I ask why it needs to be a sandbox solution? Created properly farm level isn't a problem.

Comment: It needs to be a sandbox solution because of SharePoint online (Office365).

Comment: Sharepoint online does not support Full Trust Coded (FTC) solutions at all. This means that site collections are protected from each other by a layer of security and you shouldn't try and circumvent it. However you may be able to use workflows to achieve what you require, take a look here http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/