# duplicated nodes in custom top navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, top-link-bar

Hi I have created a topNavigation class which implements PortalSiteMapProvider. the problem is that there is duplicated for the root site collection and root site collection contains only itself not other site collections. one of them goes to mydom/sitepages/startpage.aspx and the other one goes to mydom/. I would like to remove that one that goes to mydom/sitepages/startpage.aspx.
here is my code: (not publishing sites)

```
public class RIRTopNavMapProvider : PortalSiteMapProvider
{
    public override System.Web.SiteMapNodeCollection GetChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMapNode node)
    {
        SiteMapNodeCollection nodeColl = new SiteMapNodeCollection();
        PortalSiteMapNode pNode = node as PortalSiteMapNode;
        if (pNode != null)
        {
            if (pNode.Type == NodeTypes.Area && pNode.WebId == SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.ID)
            {
                SPWebApplication oWebApplicationCurrent = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
                        SPSiteCollection collSites = oWebApplicationCurrent.Sites;

                            foreach (SPSite site in collSites) //webApp.Sites)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewPages)) 
                                    {
                                        AddNavNode(nodeColl, site.RootWeb.Title, site.RootWeb.Url);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    if (site != null)
                                    {
                                        site.Dispose();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                          return nodeColl;
            }
            return base.GetChildNodes(pNode);
        }
        return new SiteMapNodeCollection();
    }

    private void AddNavNode(SiteMapNodeCollection nodeColl, string title, string url)
    {
        SiteMapNode navNode = new SiteMapNode(this, title, url, title);
        nodeColl.Add(navNode);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you deploy to the site collection root not the site for this, I think that might be the issue.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you mean, the other Site Collection has right TopNavigationbar.

Comment: If you are deploying at site level then it can cause this duplication. Please read this if you don't understand. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/explain-it-to-me-sharepoint-deployment-scope-solution-and-features

Comment: sorray by my mistake, yes I have used a feature which was web scoped to deploy the navigation bar, however when I change it to Site (site collection) it still renders dubplicate for first page.

Comment: Yes but the url you are deploying to is it a site or a site collection, ie http://sitecollection http://sitecollection/site

Comment: the ur is a site collection, every item on top navigation will be a site collection and the url goes to it.

Comment: I think there is no duplicate but it is the title of Site collection (or site) which is marked and appears in the before the top nav bar. I think it does not belong to the nav bar. how can I remove it?