# Why does my feature appear in the site collection?

Tags: feature

I have created a new feature in visual studio and scoped it to web.  I have deployed this to a site collection.  When i look at the site collections features it appears there.

Why is this?

I thought this would only appear in subsites of that site collection (because the scope is set to web).

Comment: what does the feature contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a read of this first off: [Previous stack exchange answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/explain-it-to-me-sharepoint-deployment-scope-solution-and-features)

Web targets the site, site targets the site collection etc etc.

So web is only available on the site you point it at, be it the site collection or a sub-site and only in that location. A site collection is just a special sort of site.

- Web: At the target site/site collection only
- Site: At the entire site collection and sub-sites
- WebApplication: At all Site Collections and sub-sites in target WebApp
- Farm: At all WebApplications, Site Collections and sub-sites

So if you want to target just sub-sites you need to create a deployment script that just loops through each sub-site and deploys at web level.

Comment: +1, I think I have nailed it pretty much in my earlier post. Thanks for referring it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misundestanding the difference between the Site collection and the root web.

The *Site collection* is the technical "tree" of `SPWebs`. At the root, there is also a `SPWeb` at root.

You will see your features at :

- `http://server/site/siteCollection/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx` for **Web** scoped features
- `http://server/site/siteCollection/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site` for **Site** scoped features

This image (from a previous version of SharePoint, but it's still valid) may help you to understand the concepts :

[image]