# How to create a custom list that is only available on RootWeb via Visual Studio?

Tags: list, visual-studio

I know how to create lists with Visual Studio.

I need hint on how to create the custom list named 'test' with Title, URL and an boolean field only on the RootWebs of every site collection the feature is deployed and activated on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the RootWebOnly="true" property to your custom list. The Feature with the Custom List must be scoped to Site.

```
<ListInstance Title="My custom list"
            FeatureId="00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100"
            TemplateType="100"
            Id="MyCustomList"
            Description="Simple custom list sample."
            Url="Lists/MyCustomList"
            OnQuickLaunch="true"
            RootWebOnly="true" />
```

Comment: Should I scope this feature to web or site collection level?

Comment: By default I can see that it is scoped at web level. Why site ? can you tell me.

Comment: Here's a link that explains the different scopes: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27436/explain-it-to-me-sharepoint-deployment-scope-solution-and-features

Comment: Can you also tell me whether the above code needs (ROOTWEBONLY) to go in the elements.xml file of the list or the list instance?

Comment: Well, if i remember correctly, a list instance must be site scoped and it will be available on the site collection. The RootWebOnly property makes it so that it will just be available on the Root.

Comment: Depends if you just have a List instance or a List Definition. The Property is available on both.

Comment: In the VS I can see 2 elements.xml file. 1 is under the listname and one under the listname instance

Comment: a custom list should have a Elements.xml and one SharePointProjectItem.spdata. Sorry cant help you there. Since you have a custom list it doesn't have a Definition so. Google how to create a Custom list.

Comment: Dude, I did create a custom list, I created a SP project. Then under that I did a add item -> List. Then created necessary columns. Now under the project I can see my item (listname) containing elements.xml file. Also within this item there is listnameinstance (this also contains elements.xml)

Comment: Great! now in the elementsxml just add the property in the listinstance tag.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my comment above, I can see 2 elements.xml files. One is in the listname->elements.xml and one is under listname->listnameinstance-elements.xml

Comment: My guess is that you have a list Definition: listname->listnameinstance-elements.xml and a List Instance: listname->elements.xml

Comment: When you create the Custom list, set "Create a list instance based on an existing list template" to Custom List.

Comment: I guess then it will no longer be customizable. Anyways I did the change on the listnameinstance->elements.xml and it worked.

Comment: I have 1 question. Not related maybe. But, suppose if I say RootWebOnly='FALSE'. Then, can you tell me what will happen?

Comment: This property is false by default for lists. It will "do nothing". Instead of just being on the root (If it's true) the list will be available "everywhere" on the Site Collection.

Comment: So the list will get created for every subsite. Right?

Comment: Not sure. I believe so.